# FLASH AS3 spme External streams urls not working from my server

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, streaming

Some external streaming urls working from my server, some streams urls not working , what is the reason ?I am using as3 flash 9player. external urls like this http://38.96.174.38:9568 this is not working .

Please let me know.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Problem (and solution) : `getURL()` in a Flash projector fails in Firefox

http://probertson.com/articles/2006/10/11/geturl-flash-projector-firefox-problem/

Answer (score 1):

It's dead simple: if the given server grants your player permission to access its contents via the [default policy file](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/langref/flash/system/Security.html#loadPolicyFile%28%29) (called `/crossdomain.xml`), then it works. If there is no default policy file, then it doesn't.